# How can I create a destroy test in Laravel using my controllers?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I need to create a destroy test on a row.

I have a following function for test code, but it doesn't work (In this case I need that van with a id=1 be deleted):

```
public function testDeleteVan(){
    $driver =  Driver::where('id', '=', '1')->first();
    $this->be($driver);

    $van = Van::all()->find('1');
    $this->call('GET','van/1/destroy');
    $this->assertNull(Van::all()->find($van->LP));
}
```

and in my destroy function in controller:

```
   public function destroy($id)
{
    $van = Van::find($id);
    $van->delete();
    return redirect()->route('van.index');
}
```

My routes for this problem:

```
Route::resource('van','VanController');
Route::get('van/{id}/destroy', ['uses' => 'VanController@destroy',     'as' => 'van.destroy']);
```

Comment: What's the output when you run the test?

Comment: PHPUnit 4.8.30 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.

Time: 1.2 seconds, Memory: 10.25MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)


But it doesn't delete the row with id = 1 :(

Comment: So it looks like the test is passing - are you sure it's not deleting correctly? Are you using DatabaseTransactions?

Comment: No, I dont using SatabaseTransactions. Yes, it's not deleting correctly, have you other mean for delete a row? I copy this code, but it doesn't work

Comment: I had to restart migrations and it's work xD